# How to get Aggregations in ProductCollection

Tags: search, elasticsearch, graphql

I'm customizing graphql with query Product(). 
 Instead of using searchCriteria to build searchRequest, i customed query graphql and used productCollection to build searchRequest. 
I see, the productCollection has subjectType is `Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Fulltext\Collection`. 
In class `Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Fulltext\Collection`, i want to get property $queryResponse. However, this property has scope Private.
 And ElasticSuite also dosen't support any methods to return its value @@.
 Now, i can not get data of $queryResponse. 
Please, give me solution to resolve it.